# Content ASP page received JavaScript critical error Expected ')'

Tags: c#, jquery, datetimepicker

I have a master page connected to my content page.

From my content page I try to run the Jquery DateTimePicker.

With the following code it is working:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
        $('#<%=BeginDate.ClientID%>').datetimepicker();
     });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

But when I try to add some extra variables from the original code before the master page I received the error:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
        $('#<%=BeginDate.ClientID%>').datetimepicker();
        lang: 'nl',
        timepicker: false,
        format: 'd/m/Y',
     });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

ERROR:
JavaScript critical error at line 17, column 19 in http://localhost:59009/Default.aspx\n\nSCRIPT1004: Expected ';'

Please help

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your JS syntax is incorrect. You probably want this:

```
$(function () {
       $('#<%=BeginDate.ClientID%>').datetimepicker({
           lang: 'nl',
           timepicker: false,
           format: 'd/m/Y'
       });
});
```

You want to pass those parameters **inside** the function and before closing it.